# What is Gauge.startTimer for and how to properly use it?

Tags: node.js, prometheus, gauge, prom-client

As I understand, the `Gauge` counter is a value that changes over time ***without*** saving somewhere when every change of the counter (`dec(x)` or `inc(y)`) was and the labels of every call to `dec` or `inc`.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

## Questions

- What exactly `Gauge.startTimer` does?
- What will be sent to prometheus?
- When to use it?
- How does it saves the data locally in my application?